# Check the values of a ItemTamplate Label in Datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, label, itemtemplate

I have a data Grid and there are ItemTamplate and in there are 2 Labels and they both contains some data in it.

I want to be able to loop through the whole GridView and see if any label contains the work `Keyboarding` and if it does change the value of the second label from `Incomplete` to To `fails` or `Pass`.

Here is the Code.

```html
<asp:datagrid id="dgData" runat="server" Width="658px" CellPadding="2" PageSize="2" DataKeyField="ID"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" BorderColor="AliceBlue" OnItemDataBound="dgData_ItemDataBound">
  <SelectedItemStyle ForeColor="HighlightText" BackColor="Highlight"></SelectedItemStyle>
  <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke"></AlternatingItemStyle>
  <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" BackColor="AliceBlue"></HeaderStyle>
  <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" BackColor="AliceBlue"></FooterStyle>
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Term 1" ItemStyle-Wrap="True">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:label BorderStyle=None Visible='<%# ReverseBool(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsCompleteOrNot"))) %>'   runat="server" ID="edit_Score" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Score" ) %>'>
        </asp:label>
        <asp:label BorderStyle=None Text='<%# GetCompleteIncomplete(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Score"))) %>' Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsCompleteOrNot") %>' id="txtIsComplete" runat="server">
        </asp:label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

  </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

Now the c# the Call to the server `GetCompleteIncomplete` is a method in the c# that looks at it if its 1 its Complete if its 0 its in complete:

```
protected string GetCompleteIncomplete(int iScore)
{
    if (iScore == 0)
    {
      return "Incomplete";
    }

    return "Complete";
}
```

This return the Value to the Label and shows like this. 
[image: This is how it looks like]

But I want to change that InComplete/Compete to Fail/Pass only if the First Label is `Keyboarding` other lines could stay InComplete or Complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code in your itemdatabound event:

```
if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
                   (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
{
    Label edit_Score = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("edit_Score");
    Label txtIsComplete = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("txtIsComplete");

    if (edit_Score.Text == "Keyboarding")
    {
        if (txtIsComplete.Text == "Complete")
        {
            txtIsComplete.Text = "Pass";
        }
        else if(txtIsComplete.Text == "InComplete")
        {
            txtIsComplete.Text = "Fail";
        }
    }

}
```